# How do I retrieve all polymorphic relations for one model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have setup a User model to be able to be linked with a polymorphic many to many to 3 models, let's call them A, B and C.

I have setup the models as follows:

```php
// User.php

public function a(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(A::class, 'shareable')->withPivot('view_mode');
}

public function b(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(B::class, 'shareable')->withPivot('view_mode');
}

public function c(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(C::class, 'shareable')->withPivot('view_mode');
}

// A, B and C.php

public function users(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'shareable');
}
```

Of course I created a pivot table to store the relations.

I am now trying to find a way to find ALL relations linked to a given user based on the pivot table. Let's say this is currently my data:

| user_id | view_mode | shareable_type | shareable_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RW | App\Models\A | 1 |
| 1 | R | App\Models\A | 2 |
| 1 | W | App\Models\B | 5 |
| 2 | R | App\Models\A | 2 |
| 1 | W | App\Models\C | 8 |

How can I retrieve all the related content for User with id 1?

My goal would be for it to look like this:

```
relations: [
    a: [
        - A entity with id 1
        - A entity with id 2
    ],
    b: [
        - B entity with id 5
    ],
    c: [
        - C entity with id 8
    ]
]
```

I tried by created a model named `Shareable`, and adding the following:

```
protected $table = 'shareables';

public function shareable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function a()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(A::class, 'shareable');
}
```

I then added the following to the User model:

```
public function shared()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shareable::class)->with('a');
}
```

But when I call it by doing

```
$user->shared
```

I don't get my `a` instances, only an empty collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just doublechecking: If you run `$user->shared()`, you effectively return a query, not a result. Do you have the same issue with this: `$user->shared` (without parenthesis)?

Comment: @Techno, yes my bad, I actually run `$user->shared` in my code without parenthesis (I've updated my question), so yes, I have the same issue without them.